# Multi-threading in powershell using runspace

Tags: multithreading, powershell, exchange-server

I want to load Exchange 2010 snap-in to a runspace.

```
$sessionstate = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
$sessionstate.ImportPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010","")
```

The ImportPSSnapin looks for a second argument of type PSSnapInException, but I am not sure how to put that in powershell.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Loading that snap-in outside of an actual EMS shell isn't supported by MS, and you may be better off using invoke-command against the Exchange server's remote management sessions.

Comment: I have written a powershell script which will do a synchronous operation on mailboxes enabled for audit and will put the results in a file. I wanted to change the script that i already have, and want to multi-thread it. So I want to have a runspace and will load the Exchange snapin into the runspace. In my main code, i will look for mailboxes which are audit enabled and then want to transfer control to a scriptblock which can look for all events within an audit enabled mailbox and will write to a file.

Comment: What exchange cmdlets are you using?

Comment: $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -ne "DiscoveryMailbox"}|where{$_.auditenabled -eq 'true'}                                                              $accesslog=Search-MailboxAuditLog $_.alias -StartDate $prevDate -Enddate $dateNow -ShowDetails